# Database Design for Product Promotions

Tags: mysql, database-design

Assume I have a `products` table with the following columns:

- `id` (PK)
- `category_id` (FK)
- `color_id` (FK)
- `material_id` (FK)
- `seller_id` (FK)
- `size_id` (FK)
- `name`
- `price`

Further assume that there could be *0 or more* `promotions` that apply to a product. A promotion will have a start and end date / time, a discount amount (e.g. $100 off) or percentage (e.g. 10% off), etc.

The promotion will apply only to products that match a certain criteria, such as:

- all products that are "red" color and "large" size
- all products that are under the "shirts" category
- all products sold by `seller_id` = 1 and `price` > $50

**How would I represent this in a database?** I feel that I need to associate one or more "query string" to the promotions table (e.g. `color_ids[]=1 AND sizes[]=3`) and test each product against all query strings to see if that product is part of that promotion. I expect this to be very inefficient, though.

Another option is to have a table `products_promotions` that gets set whenever a product or promotion is inserted / updated in the system, then it's just a matter of checking that table to see if the product has any promotions associated with it.

Thoughts?

Comment: How do you plan to use your promotion data? Variant 1: promotion is an additional attribute of product, insert/alter promotion (including its time expire) initiates recalculate to mark all products it is applied to (only one promotion can be applied to a product), product insert/alter initiates recalculate to obtain the promotion applied to it if exists; Variant 2: access to a product initiates searching the promotion applied to it (on the fly).

Comment: Isn't that what my question is? And aren't your Variant 1 and Variant 2 the two possible options I gave?

Comment: *Isn't that what my question is?* No. Your variant 1 looks like my variant 2, but I cannot understand does you want static or dynamic realization. Your variant 2 is similar to my variant 1 without restriction that only one promotion can be applied to one product.

Comment: I guess my question goes to "static vs dynamic" realization - and how to implement them, what their pros and cons are, etc.

Comment: *I guess my question goes to "static vs dynamic" realization* Static realization eats resources while insert/alter, dynamic realization eats resources while selecting. Think when it is more safe. I think it is better to choose a static version of the implementation - because insert/alter promotion and select data are interactive, and it is better to optimize them for to decrease the time which client spends, whereas insert/alter products (I think) is bulk and continuous, so its time increase is not so critical (if this process do not lock another processes, of course).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a table `promotions` as:

- id (PK)
- start_date
- end_date
- discount_amount
- discount_percentage
- condition

To determine the promotions the product qualifies for, you would need to dynamically execute all the queries, and select `sum(discount_amount)` and `sum(discount_percentage)`. Here is a snippet that can help you get started:

```
SET @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT id FROM products WHERE ', @condition, ' INTO @product_id');
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

You can put this snippet into a function that takes `condition` and returns `product_id`.

Running all those queries every time you `SELECT` a `product` will probably end up very time consuming. So you might want to create a table `product_discounts`, with two foreign keys to both `products` and `discounts`, to facilitate the many-to-many relationship between these two tables.

Then you insert and delete rows from `product_discounts` using either events (daily recalculation of entire relationship) or triggers on the two tables, or a combination of events and triggers.

I hope this helps.